# "The reason is that" vs. "the reason is because"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

> The reason we cannot go is [because/that] our car needs new tires.

Which word to choose?

Answer (score 3):

They both work equally well, but I am not a fan of the *is because ...* construction. It's very awkward. In most cases, you don't need both *is* and *because* in the same clause. So formally, it's *is that* or just *because.* The words *the reason* are just filler words. Informally, there's no difference.

> The reason we cannot go is that our car needs new tires.
>   We cannot go because our car needs new tires.